# jQuery problem with selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a very strange problem. I am using jQuery to intercept a particular  tag click.

I have:

```
<a class="question">lorem ipsum</a>
<a class="question_selected">lorem ipsum</a>
<a class="question">lorem ipsum</a>
<a class="question">lorem ipsum</a>
```

And my jQuery is:

```
$("a.question").click(function(){.....});
```

It should intercept the `<a>` click where class="question" but it is also intercepting whenever I click `<a class="question_selected">`.

What can be the problem?

EDIT:
I am actually changing the classes on click. The  tag that I click should become "question_selected" and all other should be "question". Here is the jQuery: `$('a.question_selected').removeClass('question_selected').addClass('question'); $(this).addClass('question_selected').removeClass('question');`

Comment: Strange indeed, it shouldn't. Are you sure `<a class="question_selected">` didn't receive an `.addClass('question')` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Your question itself is incomplete. 'whenever I click' what? Also, your event handler will fire in 1st, 3rd, and 4th 'a' click.

Comment: @Mrchief: You might want to refresh the page (which you'll probably have done by the time you see this comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the underscore from the class name. Perhaps there's a bug in jQuery regarding that.

Otherwise, this doesn't directly answer your question, but some suggestions:

First of all, instead of swapping the class, I'd just use two classes:

```
<a class="question">lorem ipsum</a>
<a class="question selected">lorem ipsum</a>
```

Then, in your jQuery, I'd cache your questions:

```
$questions = $('a.question');
```

And then your jquery can be:

```
$questions.click(function(){
    $questions.filter('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
})
```

Comment: I am not sure but it looked like jQuery had issues with me using the _. I have following DA's solution and it worked great.

Thanks a lot everyone who answered me here. All of your efforts helped me diagnose the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gJtDS/1/

This works just fine for me. Something else in your code must be conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgotten a closing tag?

Have you done anything with positioning that might place padding from another element over the top of the other one?

Are you dynamically updating the classes?  Are you assigning the click handler before or after those updates?  Are you sure you don't want `live()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.question").live('click',function(){

    $(this).removeClass('question');
    $(this).addClass('question_selected'); 

    $(this).siblings('a').removeClass(); 
    $(this).siblings('a').addClass('question'); 

});
```