# use jquery .length only on visible fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, visibility, visible

I have a form that uses javascript to dynamically add fields when an "Add field" button is clicked.  Additionally, users can remove fields by pressing a "remove field" button.  If a field is removed, it is hidden and a hidden field called '_destroy' for that field is set to true.  I am trying to make it so that a user can add a maximum of 3 fields.  So far I have the following code:

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
    if($(".order_number").length > 2){
        alert("A schedule can have a maximum of 3 tasks.")
    }else{
        //add field code here
    }
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<tr class="add-task">
    <td><input id="schedule_tasks_attributes_1394554386530_title" 
           class="field" type="text" 
           name="schedule[tasks_attributes][1394554386530][title]" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="schedule_tasks_attributes_1394554386530_order_number" 
           class="order_number" type="hidden" 
           name="schedule[tasks_attributes][1394554386530][order_number]" 
           value="4" />       
        <div id="remove_schedule_field_employer">
             <input id="schedule_tasks_attributes_1394554386530__destroy" 
               type="hidden" value="false" 
               name="schedule[tasks_attributes][1394554386530][_destroy]" />
             <a onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;" href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that the order number exists even when the field to be destroyed is hidden, so the alert message will come up even when the field is hidden.  How do I make it so that the alert message only happens when the length of visible fields is greater than 3?  I have tried the jquery .is(':visible') method but it returns a boolean, not the field, so I can't use .length on it.

UPDATE:

Maybe this will help.  This is the js that removes the field.  'fieldo' is the class that surrounds the field.

```
function remove_fields(link) {
    $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
    $(link).closest(".fieldo").hide();
}
```

Comment: Maybe check your console to see if there are any other Javascript errors halting execution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is kind of [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6560997/821057) in jQuery, issue is the underscore in class name of element.

Try removing it [see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4RAde/):

```
$(".ordernumber:visible").length
```

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't work though.  The alert won't even appear.

Comment: see demo I have added. http://jsfiddle.net/4RAde/ Here it is alerting 2 and ignoring the hidden input.

Comment: in your code if alert is not coming it means it is going to else case which is correct.

Comment: Its not correct, because there are three visible fields, so the alert should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
    if($(".order_number:visible").length > 2){
        alert("A schedule can have a maximum of 3 tasks.")
    }else{
        //add field code here
    }
}
```

This will change the jQuery selector to select elements with class `.order_number` that has display set to 'block'

Comment: “I have tried the jquery .is(':visible') method but it returns a boolean, not the field, so I can't use .length on it.”

Comment: Ah, maybe try `$(".order_number:visible").length`

Comment: Thanks, tried that too, but unfortunately its still not working.  The alert won't even appear with it.

Comment: Hmm, the :visible pseudo class looks only for CSS `display:block;` How are fields being removed?

Comment: I added the remove field code to the question content.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter(':visible')` instead of `.is(':visible')`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it also does not work. The alert doesn't even appear.

Comment: @Philip7899: Oh, when you say “hidden”, do you mean `<input type="hidden">`? `$('.order_number:not([type="hidden"])')`.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but still not working...  It still adds the field.

Comment: @Philip7899: Okay, that code did help. Thanks. Your `<input type="hidden">`s are the ones with the `order_number` class. If you don’t want to change the HTML, I think `$('.order_number').closest('td').filter(':visible').length` would work, but it would probably better, in `remove_fields`, to do something like `$(link).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1').addClass('removed')` and then check `$('.order_number:not(.removed)')`.

Comment: Thanks, this is closer.  Now the alert message appears but it will appear even when there are only two or one visible fields also.  I think its because the "addClass('removed')" is being applied to the wrong hidden field.  I think its being applied to the field with id="schedule_tasks_attributes_1394554386530__destroy" instead of the one with class="order_number".

Comment: do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try the first one?